# How can I get the position of a line break when word wrapping is on? (PyQt, QTextEdit)

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, word-wrap, qtextedit

I need to get the position of line beginnings from a QTextEdit, so that I can implement a move-point-by-line function.  It's trivial to do with this actual \n characters, but that doesn't cover me when I have word wrapping enabled.  How does QTextEdit represent which words are on which visual lines, and how can I access it?

Comment: [QTextBlock](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtextblock.html) more or less represents a line in a `QTextEdit`.

Comment: Even with word wrapping?  I tried to use textCursor.blockNumber() to create my own system for this, but that only increments with an actual new line character.  If I have word wrapping enabled, and shrink the width of the qtextedit so that a single line of text is distributed across several visual lines, the block count will not change as the cursor moves across them.  This suggests to me that QTextBlock doesn't correspond to a visual line, even if it does correspond to text lines delineated by \n.  How would you recommend using QTextBlock for this?

Comment: Did you look at the block's [layout](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtextblock.html#layout) method? I haven't tried it, but that looks like the only way to get visual lines within a logical line.

Comment: Yeah that works.  QTextLayout allows you to access individual QTextLine instances with a cursor position number, and QTextLine will give you an int for where it starts and another one for its length in characters.  That was a really helpful lead, thanks.